# Validation of java script for random photo script

Tags: javascript

On W3C Validation this gives error img not acceptable here?  any ideas:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

NumberOfImagesToRotate = 9;

FirstPart = '<img src="header';
LastPart = '.jpg" height="161" width="697" alt="header photo"/>';

function printImage() {
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfImagesToRotate);
document.write(FirstPart + r + LastPart);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I only get the error *"there is no attribute "LANGUAGE""*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error it's giving you is "No DOCTYPE found" because it's running it as HTML syntax. This, is obviously not a huge deal since you're running JavaScript Also, " The language attribute on the script element is obsolete. You can safely omit it." is another error so remove language="JavaScript" because it is obsolete now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not in to java script but just removing the language bit cured the problem.  Regards, Mel